# How to directly call to c# controller action from angular component html page

Tags: c#, angular, controller

I need to call `c#` controller action from angular component html page in directly without typescript file.
How I write a controller action `Home/Subscribe` to directly call from

`action-xhr="/Home/Subscribe"`

```
<form method="post" class="subscription-form" action-xhr="/Home/Subscribe"
            custom-validation-reporting="show-all-on-submit" target="_top" on="submit-error:submit-error.show">
        <div class="subscription-form-fieldset">
    
          <div class="subscription-form-div">
            <label class="subscription-form-label">
              <span class="subscription-form-span"></span>
              <input on="tap:submit-error.hide" class="subscription-form-input" type="email" placeholder="Type your email..."
                     name="email" id="email" required>
              <span visible-when-invalid="valueMissing" validation-for="email"></span>
              <span visible-when-invalid="typeMismatch" validation-for="email">Please, enter a valid email address.</span>
    
            </label>
          </div>
    
          <button class="subscription-form-submit" type="submit">
            Subscribe
            <div submitting class="subscription-form-submitting">
              <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>
            </div>
          </button>
        </div>
    
        <div submit-error id="submit-error" class="subscription-form-submit-error">
          <template type="amp-mustache">
            {{subscribeSubmitErrorMessage}}
          </template>
        </div>
      </form>
```

Comment: use "ngNoForm" `<form ngNoForm method=....>` to create a form not controler by Angular. NOTE: really I think that it's better create a component "SubscribeComponent" and not show the SubscribeController to mantenain the user in the Angular app

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to do it from html and not from ts file? This is not recommended. Most of the time you have to map your data, handle the errors, and you can’t do that from your html.
You should reconsider your approach